# PHP update 7.2 from 7.0 still showing old version with php -v

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, php-7.2

Updating PHP 7.0.31 to PHP 7.2 in Nginix and its updated successfully. Also updated /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default to /run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock  but Nginx  still using old version and showing older version with php -v command.
However php info showing the correct version

Answer (score 6):

Set PHP7.2 as default version:

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.2
```

Alternatively, you can run the following command to set which system wide version of PHP you want to use by default.

```
sudo update-alternatives --config php
```

[image]

Comment: Even after doing this, it's the same.

Comment: same issue for me as well, have executed both the commands suggested by you but old version of php being shown